# Appium : How to select a checkbox from a native Android application

Tags: android, xpath, appium

I want to select a checkbox from a list of fruit names .

Eg .

1.Apple      [✔]

2.Mango      [✔]

3.Banana     [✔]

This entire one row is in one relative layout , then text view and checkbox .

Relative layout[Parent]

1. //android.widget.TextView[@text='Mango']
2. //android.widget.CheckBox[@text='liked']

Now i have written function for selecting any fruit by clicking on checkbox , but my xpath is not returning any element.

```
public static void likeFruit(String fruitName){
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='"+fruitName+"']/following-sibling::android.widget.CheckBox[@text='liked']")).click();
}
```

I have tried below xpath as well , nothing is working .Am i doing anything wrong?

1.//android.widget.TextView[@text='"+fruitName+"']/../android.widget.CheckBox[@text='liked']
 2.//android.widget.TextView[@text='"+fruitName+"']/following-sibling::*[1]

Comment: Did you finally solved? I can find the element but the click is never performed.